# I used If else statement in C++, and i got opposite answer.. Check for more in info

Tags: c++

Code::Blocks 10.06

i used the following code to make a program to check whether the number 1 is divisible by number two or not however, i entered number 1 as 8, number two as 4 and it showed number one is not divisible by number two, below is my code, and i also have the program runned's photo.. [about my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxeni.jpg)

please tell me what is the error, please, i need to learn this progam, i have some targets:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, d;

    cout << "Hello guys" << endl;

    cout << "Bucky's Student21 here" << endl;
    cout << "today we are going to divide two numbers, and going to check whether one is divisible by other or not \n";

    cout << "If the number 1 is divisible by number 2, i will recognize it \n";

    cout << "enter number 1 \n";
    cin >> a;

    cout << "enter number 2 \n";
    cin >> b;

    d = a % b;
    if (d = 0) {
        cout << "number 1 is divisible by number 2 \n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "number 1 is not divisible by number 2 \n ";
    }
    cout << "Hence now as you got to know whether the number 1 is divisible by number 2 or not \n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `d=0` is an assignment. You don't want assignment.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace = with == i.e.

```
if(d==0)
{
  cout<<"something\n";
}
```